# Undefined: including a service inside another service - Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, service, scope

My NotificationService is included in my GlobalService but when I call any NotificactionService function it says: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'warn'). What I'm doing wrong? I think it is related to scope issues.

Here is my **NotificationService** code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarConfig } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class NotificationService {

  constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

  config : MatSnackBarConfig = {
    duration: 3000,
    horizontalPosition: 'right',
    verticalPosition: 'bottom'

  }

  warn(msg:string):void{
    this.config['panelClass'] = ['notification', 'warn'];
    this.snackBar.open(msg, '', this.config);
  }

}
```

Here is my **GlobalService** code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/throwError';
import { NotificationService } from '@services/notification.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GlobalService {

  constructor(private notification_srv:NotificationService){}

  public handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.status === 0) {
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error);
      this.notification_srv.warn(`An error occurred: ${error.error}`)
    } else {
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, body was: `, error.error);
      this.notification_srv.warn('Backend returned code')
    }
    return throwError('Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use one service inside another, we have to make service as a **provider** by adding that service inside a providers array in parent module(app.module.ts) as follows.

```
import { NotificationService } from '@services/notification.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [NotificationService ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: I've already tried that. Still the same error message.